# Where to put auth adapter class file in Zend 1.12

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-auth, zend-autoloader

Because I am working with legacy tables, I wrote my own `Auth_Adapter`, named `User_Auth_Adapter_DbTable`. I have a module `user` and I want to have this class there.

However, I have no idea where to actually put the file and how to name it so the Zend autoloader can find it. I have googled for more than an hour and did not find a hint, so I put it under `/application/modules/user/controller/Auth/Adapter/DbTable.php`, because it is used by the controller there. But it is not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you share some code from adapter? I think logically it must be in models folder. And the name of this class should follow Zend Framework naming conventions. So if you will put it to models/user/auth/adapter/DbTable.php class should be named as Model_User_Auth_Adapter_DbTable

Comment: If I put it under `application/modules/user/models/Auth/Adapter/DbTable.php`, it works with the class name `User_Model_Auth_Adapter_DbTable`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to define service folder.
Define folder named `service` path `/application/modules/user/service/` ([Recomended Zend-project structure](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/project-structure.project.html)), put there your adapter DbTable.php (class name must bee `Application_Modules_User_Service_DbTable`). You can call this class:

```
$adapter = new Application_Modules_User_Service_DbTable();
```